# Pycharm community 5.0, how to edit pep8 check rules

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I found the way to edit pep8 checking rules for Pycharm from here:

http://iambigblind.blogspot.de/2013/02/configuring-pep8py-support-in-pycharm-27.html

Pycharm 2.7 has the option to edit pep8 through setting -> python -> ignore error to bypass some pep8 checking.

But I could not found it in my Pycharm community 5.0 version. Anyone has the idea how to do the same thing in this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on 5.0 Pro, the pep8 settings are under
`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections`, then under `Python` in the mid-pane settings area:

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's the way to edit the rules. I see you add E126 in the ignore errors.